# Images are not getting downloaded in Telegram Official App Code

Tags: ios, iphone, telegram

I am trying to customise Telegram App Code.

I have noticed I can send Images but on the other side when I try to download the image the progress bar gets displayed and it gets stuck there with no further progress.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

The cache folder (under data\org.telegram.messenger) is probably full of stuff, you have to get rid of them through your PC because the phone isn't able to get information from this heavy folder.  Thumbnails and profile pictures (old and new) are in this folder.

Comment: I've got similar problem, and reason isn't a full cache/storage. All media (photo, vidos, gifs, event user's icons) did not loaded. Only reinstall app helps. Think of some major update without backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram is mostly blocked by local network providers. So you should check to see if this case else you will not be able to solve the “Download file failed” problem in Telegram. Contact your ISP (Internet Service Provider) and ask if this portal is blocked by them or not. And if it’s blocked, just connect your device to a VPN and then start downloading stuff from it.

If that's not the case then try resetting your Connection type by going to Settings > Advanced > Next to 'Connection type', click on 'Default (TCP used)'. Check the box 'Try connecting through IPv6'. Click 'CLOSE'. Go back to your chat and see if that fixed the issue. If not then completely uninstall Telegram and re-install.